# Does Paypal support level 2 credit card processing

Tags: paypal, credit-card

asking this after searching without specific topic/answer.

I am gonna implement paypal express checkout to deal with customers paying by credit card. They request the support of level 2 credit card processing to upload such as customer id. Failing to find right answer in paypal doc or here, I only find ( Submitting Purchasing Card Level 2 and 3 Transactions ) in paypal doc, which I think is not for credit card.( https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-purchasing-card-level-2-and-3-transactions )

Does anybody can help with piece of information/doc ? Very appreciated!

Comment: Did you get the answer? I need the exact solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, no.  PayPal Express Checkout does support some level 2 and level 3 data -- for example, tax amount, shipping ZIP code, line item details, etc.; however, this data is only recorded internally at PayPal and is not passed on to the card issuer.

If you need to submit this data, the Payflow gateway would be the way to go.  (The documents that you found on submitting level 2/level 3 data are in regards to the Payflow gateway.)  Payflow is a "bring your own bank" product, meaning that you would need to have a processing relationship with a third-party processor first (such as First Data, Chase Paymentech, TSYS, etc.), as well as your own IMA, and ensure that they support level 2/level 3 data first before signing up.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I also asked that doc indicates "Purchasing Card Level 2 and 3 ", rather than credit card, specifically. I am not very sure whether they are the same terms. I personally don't think so. Do you know the difference, if so? Thank you.

Comment: My above opinion might be wrong. I found "Visa, MasterCard, and American Express publish specific Bank Identification Number (BIN) ranges for purchasing cards" under the "Accepted BIN Ranges" section in doc ( Payflow Gateway Developer Guide and Reference )  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#submitting-purchasing-card-level-2-and-3-transactions

Comment: That's correct. Purchasing cards (that support level 2/3 data) are in different BIN ranges specifically to differentiate them from standard credit cards.